# Calculating an average from data in a variable 

Tags: c#, linq, average

I am building a basic blog module that allows the user to rate the blog posts.

The ratings are submitted via an ajax extension and held in a data table as an INT value.

When I call the ratings onto the page using a variable I would like to calculate the overall average rating.

Could anyone shed some light on how I would go about doing this?

Here is my code:

```
var rating = from x in db.DT_Control_BlogRatings
                         where x.Blog_ID == int.Parse(codesnippets.Decrypt(Request["blg"].ToString(), true))
                         select new
                         {
                             x.RatingNo,
                             x.RatingID,
                         };

            string usercount = rating.Count().ToString();

            LB_UserRating.Text = "Currently rated " + usercount + " times";
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Extract the blog id before the query, because this instruction can't be translated to SQL
int blogId = int.Parse(codesnippets.Decrypt(Request["blg"].ToString(), true));

var ratings = from x in db.DT_Control_BlogRatings
              where x.Blog_ID == blogId
              select x.RatingNo;
var avg = ratings.Average();
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked out the [`IEnumerable Average`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.average.aspx) method?

In your scenario you would use `rating.Average(r => r.RatingNo)`.

Answer (score 0):

I would say sum of all ratings for given post devided by their count will give you an average.

So you have *how often* given post was rated + *how good* it was rated function.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
double ratingAverage = rating.Average (r => r.RatingNo);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do:

```
double avg = rating.Average(rat=>rat.RatingNo);
```

However given you have the count might be nicer to:

```
int usercount = rating.Count();
double avg = rating.Sum(rat=>rat.RatingNo) / usercount;
```